# how to replace %@ with a nsstring variable? iPhone

Tags: iphone, replace, nsstring

How to replace the following correctly?

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.183:8001/GetDocument.aspx?id=%@ &  user=admin_document",self.index];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
```

I want to replace %@ with self.index.

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Is self.index is integer or string type... if string type then use %@, or if integer type then use %d

Comment: it doesn't replace %@ correctly I think, because it doesn't open the link in a uiwebview and when I give a value to id directly, it opens the link in the uiwebview.

Comment: What is `self.index`? Also a simple `NSLog(@"%@", stringURL);` after the first line would be helpful.

Comment: self.index is a nsstring variable where I hold a value.

Comment: So remove the whitespaces in the link.

Comment: Thank you Matt. The whitespaces were the problem. You are a hero.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is more likely the whitespace. Try removing it:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.183:8001/GetDocument.aspx?id=%@&user=admin_document", self.index];
NSLog(@"URL:%@", stringURL); //You can print out to check
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
```

Comment: Don't thank.. Accept =] Click the little green checkmark next to the answer that helped you most.

Comment: I had to wait 5 minutes, in order to check the little green checkmark. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespaces in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If `self.index` is not an `NSString` object, then the `%@` format specifier will not work. I suspect with a name like `index` it is probably an `NSInteger` or similar, in which case you want to use `%d` instead.

Have a look at [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for all the possible format specifiers and the types they correspond to. The compiler should pick you up on this though and suggest the correct specifier.

Comment: the problem were the whitespaces in the link. Now the problem is solved. Thank you all for your help!:)

Answer (score 0):

just parse and use it if it is integer then you use like this

```
int a=10;
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is my number %d",a];
```

and if you want to use string then you did like this

```
 NSString stringName=@"john";
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is my name %@",stringName];
```